# Is there any way to pass an arraylist in <jsp:param> n retrive it as a arraylist

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I'm passing an arraylist in `<jsp:param>` but its difficult to retrive it as an arraylist

```
<jsp:include page="attach.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="total" value="${sessionScope.file[fpr-i+1] }"/>
</jsp:include>
```

where file is a list of list of String

in the attach.jsp

```
<div id="top">
 <p>${param.total["1"]}</p>
 <p>${param.total["2"]}</p>
</div>
```

I also tried this

```
<div id="top">
 <p>${param.total[1]}</p>
 <p>${param.total[2]}</p>
</div>
```

this throws an exception

> Property '1' not found on type java.lang.String

i guess `<jsp:param>` is setting the param as a string

is there any way to retrive it as an arraylist

Comment: What about `${param.total[1]}`? You are accessing an ArrayList, so you have to use integer index, not String.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Sir i tried that too , but its still throwing that particular exception